# How to get highest and average 95th percentile over a period of time in Prometheus Query Language

Tags: prometheus, promql, percentile

I need to get the highest and average 95th percentile recorded over time in PromQL.

This query only gets the current 95th percentile.

```
histogram_quantile(
  0.95, 
  sum(
    rate(
      istio_request_duration_milliseconds_bucket{destination_workload=~"service", reporter="source"}[1m]
    )
  ) by (le, destination_workload)
)
```

Result: (current value)

```
Time    destination_workload    Value
...     service                 488
```

Because histogram_quantile outputs an instant vector, i cannot do a max_over_time() on it.

I tried this, but i get values less than 1 for some reason, and one value for each le bucket.

```
quantile_over_time(
  0.95, 
  sum(
    rate(
      istio_request_duration_milliseconds_bucket{destination_workload=~"service", reporter="source"}[1m]
    )
  ) by (le, destination_workload)[1m:]
)
```

Result:
I don't know why the values are so tiny, or why it doesn't handle the buckets.

```
Time    destination_workload    le         Value
...     service                 0.5        0
...     service                 1          0
...     service                 5          0
...     service                 10         0
...
...     service                 600000     0.167
```

We do not use Victoria Metrics.

How can i get the maximum and average 95th percentile recorded over a period of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually averaging the percentiles doesn't make sense. Here is [a great article](https://latencytipoftheday.blogspot.com/2014/06/latencytipoftheday-you-cant-average.html) on this.

To get **the max** [you could use](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#histogram_quantile):

```
histogram_quantile(
  1, 
  sum(
    rate(
      istio_request_duration_milliseconds_bucket{destination_workload=~"service", reporter="source"}[1m]
    )
  ) by (le, destination_workload)
)
```

To get **the average** [you could use](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/histograms/#count-and-sum-of-observations) (*_sum* and *_count* metrics are provided by Histogram as well as *_bucket*):

```
rate(istio_request_duration_milliseconds_sum{destination_workload=~"service", reporter="source"}[1m])
/
rate(istio_request_duration_milliseconds_count{destination_workload=~"service", reporter="source"}[1m])
```

---

## Prometheus Subquery

If you really know what you're doing and you really need taking the max and the average on the calculated percentile, you could use [the Subquery](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/) to get a range vector of calculated percentiles.
The range vector in that case is a result of subsequent invocations of the instant-vector function (f.e. `histogram_quantile`) for some duration (f.e. last `5 min`) with some resolution (f.e. `each 1 min`).

Average 95p over last 5 min with the 1 min step:

```
avg_over_time(histogram_quantile(0.95, sum(rate(demo_api_request_duration_seconds_bucket[5m]))by(le))[5m:1m])
```

Max 95p over last 5 min with the 1 min step:

```
max_over_time(histogram_quantile(0.95, sum(rate(demo_api_request_duration_seconds_bucket[5m]))by(le))[5m:1m])
```

Comment: The subquery ones work well.  thanks!  we need this so we know what the p95 usually is so we can build a baseline.  the min/max (i.e. highest p95) is for self-throttling.  if resptime is not higher than the max it was within an hour, but otherwise triggerable, it would assume it already triggered and self-throttle to keep the alert from sending repeat notifications unless it gets worse.

Comment: after reading that article, i wonder if replacing avg_over_time(v) with quantile_over_time(0.95, v), will get me closer to what i want.